# How to solve npm dependencies with other packages?

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I have an angular app with these dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "personalUiLibrary": "1.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "tailwindcss": "^2.2.7"
}
```

in `personalUiLibrary` package.json I have this devDependency:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "tailwindcss": "^2.2.7"
}
```

Into my angular app I need to update the `tailwindcss` version from `2.2.7` to `3.0.0`
If i try to launch

```
npm i tailwindcss@latest
```

it goes well but I have an error:

```
Error: Can't resolve 'tailwindcss/lib/util/prefixNegativeModifiers' in 
'/myapp/node_modules/personalUiLibrary...'
```

Is there a way to have two versions of the same package into my package.json?

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` - It tells NPM to ignore peer deps and proceed with the installation anyway

you can read more about how npm works internally [here](https://dev.to/shree_j/how-npm-works-internally-4012)